# How to add Content Security Policy to Safari extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension, browser-extension

I am trying to develop the safari extension which does cross script loading.
but i am getting the content security policy directive error.

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive:

In chrome by adding the content security policy in my manifest.json file i could get away with it. How can i do it for safari extension

Any help or clues are mostly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the content script policy for Safari extensions. It is whatever Safari sets it to be. unfortunately no one really knows what it is.

I ran into the same problem with my code (inline scripts). I changed my code. if you are using something like

`<body onload="foo()"></body>`

Then you probably don't want to do that. You can change by using event listeners on DOM events like "load" or "DOMContentLoaded".

If you could share some of your code I could help better.